# After changing web host, I get a 'file does not exist' error

Tags: web-hosting, php, wordpress, redirects, chmod

I run a WordPress blog, and have recently changed web hosts.

When changing web hosts, I copied all files and exported/imported the database etc as explained by lots of tutorials found easily on Google. The blog home page works fine.

**What goes wrong:**

When I click on any link from the home page, the browser gets stuck in a redirect loop. Looking at the error log, I see:

> File does not exist: /usr/local/apache/htdocs/index.php

The directory /usr doesn't even exist for my website - so perhaps this is looking for a file that was present using my old Web Host and is no longer present with my new web host?

---

What is going on, and how might I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weirdly, after changing the permissions on .htaccess from 744 to 644, everything works great. If someone wants to explain this, then go for it!

Comment: read htaccess - it may have rewrite rules, which fix problems. With old rights file (maybe) wasn't read by httpd-daemon

Answer (score 0):

Have you contact your hosting provider about this issue? I think Wordpress need to be installed by your current provider, then you can upload your files to your root folder. Please contact your hosting provider first and ask for the solution. If they cant solve it, you need to consider to switch again your hosting provider, you can check asphostcentral.com. Good luck